# How can I show different content with one activity when clicking the same button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I create some google maps markers from a JSON file with a for loop. Furthermore, I created a onInfoWindowClick method to show more information and there I also launch a new activity. Now my question is how I can make the onInfoWinodwClick launch the activity with the specific content of my marker.

I already tried this, but I only have one marker as you can see in the following code snipped:

```
    @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RecyclerViewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String infoArrayString;

if (marker.equals(myMarker1)) 
{

//Assuming you have JSONArray of information to show on the next screen

infoArrayString = markerJson1.toString();
bundle.putString("info",infoArrayString);

}else if(marker.equals(myMarker2){

//info for marker2

}
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here I create the markers just imagine a for loop which loops this trough only with different latitude and longitude coordinates:

```
 LatLng companies = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(companies)
                                        .title(companyName)
                                        .snippet("Anzahl der Stellen: " + jobCounter + "\n" + ultimateJobTitles)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.maps_icon2)));
                                jobCounter = 0;

                                mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MarkerInfo.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: What specific content of my marker you wanna pass to next activity?

Comment: @AliAhsan I want to display different company names preferred in a recyler view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save each marker related info using `Tag` at the time of marker creation

```
// set related info as tag
marker1.setTag(markerJson1.toString());
```

then, you can get the related info in `onMarkerClick` method as follows

```
// to retrieve the info from clicked marker
String info = (String) marker.getTag();// Type cast to your object type;
```

Cheers:)